# PGBouncer : Cant connect on the right db

Tags: postgresql, pg, pgbouncer

I'm actually facing an issue. I've installed pgbouncer on a production server, on which i've a Odoo instance and postgresql as well.

Perhaps :

In my logs, i'm having this :

```
2018-09-10 16:39:16.389 10123 WARNING C-0x1eb5478: 
(nodb)/(nouser)@unix(18272):6432 pooler error: no such database: postgres
2018-09-10 16:39:16.389 10123 LOG C-0x1eb5478: (nodb)/(nouser)@unix(18272):6432 login failed: db=postgres user=oerppreprod
```

Here is the actual conf of pgbouncer :

```
pgbouncer_archive = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=archive
admin_users = postgres
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
```

With aswell, the default config (i've only added/edited this).

Why is he trying to connect on the `postgres` database ?

When i go back on the previous conf (without PGBouncer, just swapping from port 6432 to 5432), everything is working ....

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and in my situation. Maybe it will be usefull to somebody:

I have solved this by a few steps:

1. At the beginning of every request - your Framework or PDO (or else) running the initial query to check if database you asking is exists in the postgres data to process you request.
2. I have replaced the part of line "**user=project_user password=mytestpassword**" from the database section of pgbouncer.ini file. As I tested, if you replace this part - then the pgbouncer will use your userlist.txt file (or your selected auth), in my case, it was the userlist.txt.
3. Added the line "**postgres = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres**"

   [databases]

   postgres = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres

   my_database = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=my_database
4. My userlist.txt file looks like this (I am using auth_type = md5, so my password was in md5):

   "my_user" "md5passwordandsoelse"
5. I have added my admin users to my pgbouncer.ini file:

   admin_users = postgres, my_user

After all manipulations I advise you to check from which user u are running queries, by usin this simple query:

```
select current_user;
```

At the end, with this query you must to receive you selected username (in my case it was - my_user)
p.s. also I must to mention, that I was using 127.0.0.1 - because my pgbouncer is installed on the same server with postgres.